# SonarQube failed to complete the review of this commit: unable to retrive author for commit

Tags: sonarqube, gitlab-ci

I can't find anything about this online at all. The only search returns are from the source code itself.

[https://www.google.com/search?site=&source=hp&q=%22unable+to+create+retrive+author%22&oq=%22unable+to+create+retrive+author%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..33i22i29i30k1l4.4603.10463.0.10991.41.19.0.0.0.0.984.2208.0j2j1j5-1j1.5.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..36.3.1063...0.O7TJHAo3Irg](https://www.google.com/search?site=&source=hp&q=%22unable%20to%20create%20retrive%20author%22&oq=%22unable%20to%20create%20retrive%20author%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..33i22i29i30k1l4.4603.10463.0.10991.41.19.0.0.0.0.984.2208.0j2j1j5-1j1.5.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..36.3.1063...0.O7TJHAo3Irg)

The title states what the problem is. I've never seen this error, but now it occurs for every pipeline I run. I don't know why or when it started. If I figure this out I'll post solution.

I'll check SonarQube permissions and try to make sure everything is configured properly.

```
17:07:07.624 INFO: ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL
17:07:07.625 DEBUG: IssuesSeverityBreaker is disabled (sonar.buildbreaker.preview.issuesSeverity == DISABLED)
17:07:07.625 DEBUG: QualityGateBreaker is disabled (sonar.analysis.mode != publish)
17:07:07.627 DEBUG: Post-jobs : GitLab Commit Issue Publisher (wrapped)
17:07:07.627 INFO: Executing post-job GitLab Commit Issue Publisher (wrapped)
17:07:07.757 ERROR: SonarQube failed to complete the review of this commit
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to create retrive author for commit 7ee2dab421610f30a8b
    at com.talanlabs.sonar.plugins.gitlab.CommitFacade.getUsernameForRevision(CommitFacade.java:228)
    at com.talanlabs.sonar.plugins.gitlab.CommitIssuePostJob.updateGlobalComments(CommitIssuePostJob.java:177)
    at com.talanlabs.sonar.plugins.gitlab.CommitIssuePostJob.execute(CommitIssuePostJob.java:72)
    at org.sonar.scanner.postjob.PostJobWrapper.executeOn(PostJobWrapper.java:58)
    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.PostJobsExecutor.execute(PostJobsExecutor.java:65)
    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.PostJobsExecutor.execute(PostJobsExecutor.java:54)
    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.AbstractPhaseExecutor.execute(AbstractPhaseExecutor.java:81)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:178)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:144)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:129)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:259)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:254)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:243)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:144)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:129)
    at org.sonar.scanner.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:47)
    at org.sonar.scanner.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:86)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:144)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:129)
    at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:118)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:117)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:233)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedScanner.java:151)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.runAnalysis(Main.java:123)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:77)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:61)
Caused by: com.talanlabs.gitlab.api.GitLabAPIException: {"message":"403 Forbidden  - Not authorized to access /api/v4/users"}
    at com.talanlabs.gitlab.api.http.GitLabHTTPRequestor.handleAPIError(GitLabHTTPRequestor.java:378)
    at com.talanlabs.gitlab.api.http.GitLabHTTPRequestor.toPaged(GitLabHTTPRequestor.java:149)
    at com.talanlabs.gitlab.api.services.GitLabAPIUsers.getUsers(GitLabAPIUsers.java:59)
    at com.talanlabs.sonar.plugins.gitlab.CommitFacade.getUsernameForRevision(CommitFacade.java:214)
    ... 32 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: https://gitlab.company.com/api/v3/users?search=first.m.last%40company.com
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1876)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1474)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
    at com.talanlabs.gitlab.api.http.GitLabHTTPRequestor.parse(GitLabHTTPRequestor.java:336)
    at com.talanlabs.gitlab.api.http.GitLabHTTPRequestor.toPaged(GitLabHTTPRequestor.java:144)
    ... 34 common frames omitted

17:07:07.839 INFO: Task total time: 12.279 s
17:07:07.839 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
17:07:07.839 INFO: EXECUTION SUCCESS
17:07:07.839 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
17:07:07.839 INFO: Total time: 15.686s
17:07:07.951 INFO: Final Memory: 49M/449M
17:07:07.951 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
17:07:07.951 DEBUG: Execution getVersion
17:07:07.951 DEBUG: Execution stop
Process returned exit code 0
The SonarQube Scanner has finished
17:07:08.303  Creating a summary markdown file...
17:07:08.303  Analysis results: http://server:9000/dashboard/index/ft-hzn-sps-db
17:07:08.304  Post-processing succeeded.
Creating cache default...
Created cache
Job succeeded
```

Comment: Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: https://gitlab.company.com/api/v3/users?search=first.m.last%40company.com

Answer (score 2):

Here is what the logs tell us about your problem:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to create retrive author for commit 7ee2dab421610f30a8b
```

SonarQube tries to get an author of the git commit `7ee2dab421610f30a8b`, because it uses that *blame* information to automatically assign issues and to show this kind of information in the UI. However retrieving the author does not work for these reason:

```
com.talanlabs.gitlab.api.GitLabAPIException: {"message":"403 Forbidden  - Not authorized to access /api/v4/users"}
```

The framework, that is used to access this information in git tried to access an api, but got an authorization exception (http code 403).

```
Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: https://gitlab.company.com/api/v3/users?search=first.m.last%40company.com
```

Something went wrong, when trying to search for a user with the email adress `first.m.last@company.com` (which seems to be a fake email address).

So to fix this issue, you should give the user that runs the SonarQube analysis sufficient privileges and you should check, that your git history does not contain unusual data.